# IoT hub RegistryManager - How to change device's primary key from backend?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-iot-hub

In an Azure IoT backend, how can I use the Microsoft.Azure.Devices.RegistryManager (or another class if that's what I need) to change a device's primary key?

Comment: What about using the REST API? more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/digitaltwinmodel/service/createorupdatedevice

Answer (score 0):

The following line will recycle the device symmetric keys:

```
var device = registryManager.UpdateDeviceAsync(new Device(deviceId), true).Result;
```

in the case of changing only a device primary key:

```
var device = registryManager.GetDeviceAsync(deviceId).Result;
var auth = new AuthenticationMechanism();
auth.SymmetricKey.PrimaryKey = "<new primary key>";
auth.SymmetricKey.SecondaryKey = device.Authentication.SymmetricKey.SecondaryKey;
device = registryManager.UpdateDeviceAsync(new Device(deviceId) { Authentication = auth}, true).Result;
```

or you can simplified it:

```
var device = registryManager.GetDeviceAsync(deviceId).Result;
device.Authentication.SymmetricKey.PrimaryKey = "<new primary key>";
device = registryManager.UpdateDeviceAsync(device, true).Result;
```